Which package should I be downloading for my Linux Ubuntu computer, 64 os?
So there are

linux (tgz)
ARM linux
RISC-V linux
PPC64 linux

But I've got no idea what the differences are, aside from a guess that ARM Linux is meant to be run from lower-level-heavy Linux versions.
For context I'm downloading Bitcoin Core mainly with the intention of looking through the code, tinkering with UI, and learning more to potentially take over to some of my blockchain projects. Any help would be awesome!

ARM, RISC and PPC refer to comparatively uncommon types of CPU for desktop PCs. ARM is dominant for phones and probably used in many Android tablets.
If those terms are unfamiliar to you,  you almost certainly need the plain (tgz) version intended for the  Intel x86 / AMD 64 architecture machines that are almost all PCs sold in recent decades.
If you want to read the source code, all four are probably derived from common code. Download the source, not an installable binary
